# PowerPoint Content add-in - Arrange not works

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I create new PowerPoint Content web add-in.

I want use add-in behind a text. For this I make for add-in `"Send to back"` and for text make `"Bring to front"`. But in slide an add-in stay always on top see attached image.[image]

Notice: in preview panel arrange works but in slide not. In slide show mode (F5) also not works.

PowerPoint version:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue. Content Add-ins (Agaves) do not participate in the Z order within a slide.